# Searching a large number of texts in php

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, elasticsearch

I have a project, it's based on Symfony2, that allows a user to create a number of rules for assigning items to different categories. It is a backend project, so there will be only a few users accessing it.

Rules are based on phrases, items are text objects. I am trying to figure out a best way to search and apply rules to those text objects as quickly and smoothly as possible.

For example, if a user creates 5 rules (phrases: `basketball`, `football`, `baseball`, `swimming`, `running`), and all text objects matching any of these phrases should be assigned to SPORTS category, I figured I could use ElasticSearch to quickly return IDs of those objects and then using a simple INSERT or UPDATE mysql query save the assignment.

I am worried about the performance, if there would be, for example, 1 milion text objects in index and say, there are 50k objects matching those rules, running search queries in parts, for example limiting the scope to 50k for each ElasticSearch query (to iterate over the whole index), then updating/inserting data to MySQL would be an acceptable approach?

So, running query (pseudo):

```
$ids = elasticSearch->setPhrases('basketball OR baseball OR football')->find()->limit(1, 50000);
$ids = elasticSearch->setPhrases('basketball OR baseball OR football')->find()->limit(50000, 100000);
```

etc.

Is ElasticSearch a good choice for that kind of processing? Or should I stick to MySQL and run queries using regexp for example (in chunks of course)?

Maybe there are existing solutions I could check? Unfortunately, I am limited to PHP and Symfony2, but if there are any better solutions worth checking, I might be able to suggest it to the client.

Hope someone can help me, any help is more then welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you are using `text` fields, you can create a `FULLTEXT` index on your table:

```
CREATE TABLE texts(
    id int not null auto_increment primary key,
    text_field1 text,
    text_field2 text,
    text_field3 text
)Engine = MyISAM;  -- InnoDB supports fulltext indexes since v5.6

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX itexts on texts(text_field1,text_field2,text_field3);
```

Then you can search using fulltext expressions (finding at least one term):

```
SELECT * FROM texts 
WHERE MATCH (text_field1,text_field2,text_field3) 
AGAINST ('basketball baseball football');
```

Or finding all terms

```
SELECT * FROM texts 
WHERE MATCH (text_field1,text_field2,text_field3) 
AGAINST ('+basketball +baseball +football');
```

Now in your project you can translate your rules to fulltext search expression and execute it using a regular symfony query.

More info about FULLTEXT search:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ivan, I am familiar with fulltext in MySQL, though didnt know that it's already supported for InnoDB tables, need to check the docs. Thanks!

Comment: Also, is there a way to tell which phrase was matched when using fulltext search? For example, i search for items matching at least one of phrases: basketball, football, baseball. MySQL returns 100 records, is there a way to tell for each of the returned records which phrase was matched?

Comment: You can add the expression:
`MATCH (text_field1,text_field2,text_field3) 
AGAINST ('+basketball +baseball +football')` as column_name and order by that column to get records with high  match ratio.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, but that's not exactly what I need, it gives me score, not the phrase(s) that matched each record.

Comment: One more problem i've encountered while playing with fulltext is handling of special characters, for example when trying to find records that contain part of URL: "nba.com/players" it returns records that match nba, com or players. Any way to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

This is absolutely what Elasticsearch excels at.  For example, I have an index on my laptop (Macbook Air, so nothing beefy) that has 4,095,005 documents representing different names.

#### Using filters

The use-case you are requesting is basically just exact-match filtering.  For that, we can use Elasticsearch *filters*, which are very fast.  Here is an example filter that looks for five different names:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test_names/_search" -d'
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "term": {
                "first_name": "miguel"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "first_name": "ella"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "first_name": "almeta"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "first_name": "garret"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "first_name": "simon"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    } 

  }
}'
```

And the top portion of the response:

```
{
 "took": 85,
 "timed_out": false,
 "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
 },
 "hits": {
    "total": 3755,
    "max_score": 1,
 ....
```

The `took: 85` means it took 85ms to filter 4 million documents and find the matching 3755.  If I run the same filter again, I get:

```
{
 "took": 4,
 "timed_out": false,
 "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
 },
 "hits": {
    "total": 3755,
    "max_score": 1,
 ....
```

Now the execution time is just 4ms.  This is because Elasticsearch caches filter bitsets, so subsequent searches for "miguel", "ella", "almeta", "garret" or "simon" will execute blazingly fast (until those values are evicted from cache)

#### Using queries

Queries provide more robust full-text searching, and will rank documents based on how well they match.  So you could do something like this instead:

```
curl -XGET "http://localhost:9200/test_names/_search" -d'
{
  "query" : {
    "match": {
      "first_name": "miguel ella almeta garret simon"
    }
  }
}'
```

Which is basically the equivalent to "miguel OR ella OR almeta OR garret OR simon", but weighted so that documents which match more terms have a higher score.  It executes in 54ms (again searching 4m documents on my laptop):

```
{
   "took": 54,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 5,
      "successful": 5,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3755,
      "max_score": 0.8923058,
    ...
```

This is just scratching the surface of what Elasticsearch can do.  But I would definitely say that it can provide the functionality you are describing, and do it very, very fast.